# how to instantiate Unit in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, concurrency, hashmap, set

All I desire is to use some concurrent Set (that appears not to exist at all). Java uses `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap<K, Void>` to achieve that behavior. I'd like to do sth similar in Scala so I created instance of Scala HashMap (or Java ConcurrentHashMap) and tried to add some tuples:

```
val myMap = new HashMap[String, Unit]()
myMap + (("myStringKey", Unit))
```

This of course crashed the process of compilation as Unit is abstract and final.

How to make this work? Should I use `Any`/`AnyRef` instead? I must ensure nobody inserts any value.

Thanks for help

Comment: Note, `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap<K, void>` is wrong. The `Void` type (notice capital `V`) can only accept the `null` value, but [the documentation for `ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) specifically disallows `null` keys/values in the map. How this really is usually implemented is `ConcurrentHashMap<K, Boolean>`, using constant `Boolean.TRUE` for the values. (Using the constant `Boolean.TRUE` ensures that you don't create a new `Boolean` instance for each entry in the map.)

Comment: correction (void -> Void) proceeded, using `Boolean.TRUE` is nice trick, thanks

Comment: are you sure you should even be using `Unit` there? how about `Option` or a custom ADT (sealed case class family)?

Comment: I am definitely not sure, I just need concurrent set - I used the Boolean trick and it works fine.

Comment: This question is indeed a very valid question independent of the given context and the use case. You need a way to instantiate Unit types in functional programming languages, as it's a very important building block to create ADTs and identity functions on them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can just use `()` whose type is `Unit`:

```
scala> import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap

scala> val myMap = new HashMap[String, Unit]()
myMap: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,Unit] = Map()

scala> myMap + ("myStringKey" -> ())
res1: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Unit] = Map(myStringKey -> ())
```

This is a comment taken from [`Unit.scala`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/Unit.scala):

> There is only one value of type `Unit`, `()`, and it is not represented by any object in the underlying runtime system.

Comment: Maybe add that when you say `val x = ()`, what you get is the boxed value, `scala.runtime.BoxedUnit.UNIT`. Also, `()` has type Unit: to say "return type" might confuse people because of paren usage in function applications. The unit value looks like an empty tuple, not a weird application.